# Adding a TAB BAR to a uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview, uitabbar

I have an app designed with storyboards. I'm trying to add a tab bar at the bottom of the view where i have my uitableviewcontroller , problem is it automatically drags it under the first cell .

I intend to add 4 buttons on the tab bar each performing a certain action INSIDE this view ( each one will reload the table with different data from the web ) .

Comment: It sounds like a `UIToolBar` suits your needs the most. A tab bar is for navigation. Not to perform actions.

Comment: Create MCVE to explain the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, UIToolBar would be the best option for you. You would place it at the bottom of your view controller and create IBActions for each button that update your data.

If you are intent on using a UITabBar, then you need to rethink your storyboard layout. You would have a UITabBarController as the initial view, which would have your TableViewController subclass as the root view. You can either make four separate TableViewController subclasses (each for a different dataset) or you can have a single subclass that receives a load message from the UITabBarController on what dataset to load.

If you decide to use a toolbar, it isn't possible to add it to the bottom of a default Interface Builder TableViewController. Follow these steps to add a toolbar to the bottom of your TableViewController subclass:

1. Insert a `UIViewController` into the storyboard (this will replace your `UITableViewController`)
2. Set the class of your new `UIViewController` to your `UITableViewController` subclass (Identity Inspector)
3. Insert a `UIToolbar` at the bottom of your new `UIViewController` and add buttons, IBOutlets, and IBActions as desired.
4. Add a `UITableView` to your `UIViewController` that takes up the rest of the screen space.
5. In the connections inspector, connect the dataSource and delegate of your `UITableView` to your `UITableViewController` subclass
6. Add and configure as many prototype TableViewCells as necessary.

This should be all that is necessary to get a toolbar in your TableViewController. It requires extra configuration in the Interface Builder, but it is the only way to do it without writing extra code.

Comment: The thing is i don't think i need a tabbarcontroller , all i want is 4 buttons on the bottom of the screen , each one connected to an IBAction that will reset the table data . Problem is no matter what i add to the tableviewcontroller it attaches it to the bottom of the first cell.

Comment: I added the steps to get a toolbar on your view. I wrote this from memory, so I may have missed a step. If I did please let me know, otherwise please mark it as the correct answer. Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting the following error : [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Yfd-OW-gAN-view-aED-XN-o5u" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Answer (score 2):

Select your controller then menu `Editor > Embed In > Tab Bar Controller`

EDIT : hu i did not read your question entirely. Others answers are more correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I intend to add 4 buttons on the tab bar each performing a certain
>   action INSIDE this view ( each one will reload the table with
>   different data from the web ).

As per your last sentence, I have judged that you neither need a tab bar nor tableviewcontroller. You just need a simple **View controller** having a **Tableview** *at top*, and **toolbar** *at bottom*. Toolbar would have a **segment control** with 4 sections - which will act as four buttons. On each section tap, you can capture event of value changed, and load new data in table according to selected index.

It's an easy way of doing thing. Don't make your life complex by using tab bar :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what i eventually did. 
I was getting an error in the method mentioned by user2105505 ( marked as correct) , so i decided to create a UIVIEWCONTROLLER and add my tableviewcontroller as a child of that uiviwewcontroller (by importing the uitableviewcontroller class , creating an isntance of the class and instantiating on self.storyboard) , then added the toolbar to the uiviewcontroler.

Then just add the tableview as a subview of the uiviewcontroller view , BUT you need to remember to do two things.

Instantiate your toolbar, and modify the size of the tableview so it fits and the toolbar shows.(maybe use bringToFront as an alternative?didn't work for me, had to specify the size manually ).